# Javascript doesn't show elements with display = "block"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a `<div>` via javascript that has `display:hidden;` in its css. I want to make it a block element, but it won't appear. Here is my code.

```
var fatGooseShop = document.createElement('div');
            fatGooseShop.width = canvas.width / 1.5 + "px";
            fatGooseShop.height = canvas.height / 1.5 + "px";
            fatGooseShop.style.position = "absolute";
            fatGooseShop.style.left = "50%";
            fatGooseShop.style.top = "50%";
            fatGooseShop.style.margin = "-" + (canvas.height / 1.5) / 2 + "px 0px 0px -" + (canvas.width / 1.5) / 2 + "px";
            fatGooseShop.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            fatGooseShop.style.display = "none";
function shop()
{
    fatGooseShop.style.display = "block";
}
```

I call the `shop()` function from the browser to run it, if that makes a difference.

Comment: `display: hidden` or `visibility: hidden`?

Comment: have you defined the Canvas variable further up in the code?

Comment: hey guy.append your element into one element to show .

Answer (score 3):

1. Firstly You need to append the element

   > ```
   > document.getElementById("test").appendChild(fatGooseShop);
   > ```
2. There's no content and you're not actually setting the width, or height of the block, so it's not going to be visible. You need to modify your code as follows. Note: This will work, provided `canvas.width` is returning a non
   zero value

> ```
> fatGooseShop.style.width = canvas.width / 1.5 + "px";
> fatGooseShop.style.height = canvas.height / 1.5 + "px";
> ```

## Example Here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/cqbzw/6/

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the element as well

```
x=document.getElementById("something");
x.appendChild(fatGooseShop);
```

Comment: Oh gosh.. I feel like such an idot for forgetting that. I fixed that part now, but when I run the shop() function it still doesn't show.

Answer (score 2):

You create the element with createElement, but you need to `appendChild` it to another element in the DOM before it will appear. Once that's done you can manipulate it.

Comment: It is possible to manipulate it before appending, but it has no effect until it's appended.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to append it to the document. In your JS file add the line line below the `//Javascript`.

```
<!--HTML-->
<div id="the-div">

</div>

//Javascript
document.getElementById("the-div").appendChild(fatGooseShop);
```